# One page website with a series of panels, each the size of the viewport

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design, viewport

I've been looking for a way to accomplish this but can't seem to find the answer.
I want to create a one-page website that would be composed of a series of panels, each the size of the viewport (both in height and width) and with different background colors.

So, when I get on the page, my viewport is filled with panel 1, then I can scroll down to panel 2 which will also completely fill the viewport.

Here's a quick test page to illustrate what I mean: http://dev.manifold.ws/test/
But, obviously, what I'd want is each panel's height to be 100% of the viewport (not a fixed height).

Here's a more complex site that's successfully doing it: http://www.deuxhuithuit.com

I feel there must be a fairly simple way to achieve this but I can't seem to find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Do I need some jQuery?
Should I rely on a plugin?
Or is there a way to do this with CSS?

Thanks,

-Thom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like I figured it out after all. It was really simple, in the end.
No need for jQuery or a plugin.
I updated my test page with a working example: http://dev.manifold.ws/test/

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>

  <section id="red">
  </section>

  <section id="blue">
  </section>

  <section id="green">
  </section>

</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
html,body {
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#red {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
background:#F00;
}

#blue {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
background:#00F
}

#green {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
background:#0F0;
}
```

Pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Is there a reason you used the 'position: relative' for each section? I tried without and it seems to work fine, just wondering...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after the One Page Nav jQuery plugin:

http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin/

Here's a demo:
http://trevordavis.net/play/jquery-one-page-nav/

I saw this implemented on a StackOverflow question just this morning:
http://www.visualwayofthinking.com/en/

Click on the tabs at the top to see the animation.

Comment: Hi, that's nice plugin but that's not what I'm after. My main issue is setting the height of a div so that it's 100% of the viewport, meaning 100% of the visible portion of the page within the window.